# Average array by intervals

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, average

I have a 2D array of floats which looks like this (data [here](http://pastebin.com/ARgJJY2J)):

[image]

As you can see, the values are not unique and a single x value can have several y values.

I'd like to produce a *single average curve* by taking the average of the y values for those points inside given intervals in the x axis.

I could set 20 intervals in the x axis and iterate on every interval searching for the y values whose x values are located in it. Here's the MWE:

```
import numpy as np

# Define array with the data.
a = [[lots of floats][lots of floats]]

# Define intervals in x.
interv_x = np.linspace(14., 24., 20)
interv_y = []
for i, x in enumerate(interv_x):
    if i < len(interv_x) - 1:
        y_lst = []
        # Search for points inside this interval.
        for j, y_val in enumerate(a[1]):
            if x <= a[0][j] < interv_x[i + 1]:
                y_lst.append(y_val)
        # Average the y values of all these points.
        interv_y.append(np.average(y_lst))

# Plot results.
plt.scatter(a[0], a[1], c='b', s=10)
plt.scatter(interv_x[:-1], interv_y, c='r', s=50)
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

where the red dots are the averaged values.

Is there a way to do this with a function? I'm open to solutions involving `numpy` and/or `scipy`.

Comment: Are you looking to plot a smooth curve kinda thing?